# Seagate 3TB hard drive loses format information

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a Windows 7x64 Ultimate, 6 GB memory, 1 TB HD. 3TB Barracuda XT HDD. The HDD is installed on a StarTech 4 bays external enclosure
I had troubles so I converted to a GPT, created 1 partition and formatted as NTFS. 
The hard drive I can write and read to and from the hard drive but it will become unreadable at some point while I am copying files or after I have copied files to it.

I have copied large Bluray movies and diverse video files, I have also copied 32 GB of pictures, and I have copied about 86 thousand music files in different formats.  At some point the partition becomes unreadable and I have to format the partition again (all files lost) and I have to start the whole process again.  At some point I have been unable to copy large ISO (Bluray movies) file images.

I have partitioned the HDD in 2 partitions P1 - 2TB, P2 - 1TB and I have lost every single file in either partition the same way.  I reformat the HDD and it seems fine.

I have run seatools to check the hard drive and it reports to be OK.

What gives?

Comment: It sounds like you can use the drive, but at some point it becomes corrupt and you have to re-partition.  Can you try mounting it internally and see if that helps?  Otherwise I'd just say its a bad drive and return it.

Comment: Does your external enclosure support 3tb GPT disks? Have you tried the 3tb drive in another enclosure as a test? My money is on the encolsure causing the problems.

Comment: It sounds like the enclosure is to blame.  You have had problems so you converted to GPT.  You still have problems.  The only thing that remained the same is the enclosure.